# Replacing Bad Node in Zookeeper Quorum Safely

Tags: apache, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

We have 5 node zookeeper quorum `( A,B,C,D,E )` running in production, 1 node went down last week`( E )` . quorum is healthy but we need to replace `( E )` with new healthy node `( F )`

I am juggling between 2 options

```
1. add ( F ) to the quorum and then remove  ( E )
2. replace ( F ) with ( E ) restart followers and then restart leader
```

I tested Option #2, I can see that `( F )` is accepted in quorum after leadership is forced ( by restarting leader )

Quorum is healthy, but I just wanted to make sure if this is standard procedure

I dont find any apache documentation about node replacement for this version

```
ZK Version : 3.4.6
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, for versions prior to 3.5.*, reconfiguration of a ZK cluster requires coordinated restarts **after ensuring the configuration is updated to replace the old node with the new one**, so that the new node(s) could join the quorom and old one is removed. I had found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/miketheman/6057930) helpful.

In general, for upgrades also, it's recommended to go with rolling restarts - reference [apache link](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ZooKeeper/FAQ#A6).

If possible, I suggest you consider upgrading to 3.5* version wherein [dynamic reconfiguration](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperReconfig.html#ch_reconfig_intro) is possible without any restarts.

Comment: We hit this issue recently https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/ZOOKEEPER-1576 we will upgrade to 3.5.x in near future for now we want to patch the existing verion

Comment: The gist above starts out with the assumption that I have an ensemble of three nodes. But If I start out with three and one breaks, it is not possible to do this without downtime, is it?

Answer (score 0):

If in your example node F can be brought up to have the same IP* and ID (written in zookeeper data as myid file) as the failed node E, then no further action is needed. The new node F will initially have no data, but it will receive the latest data from the other available nodes. I have verified with Zookeeper version 3.4.10.

*This scenario is possible for example on AWS where you can reserve IP addresses for Zookeeper nodes through ENIs. So a new node F can be given the same IP address as a failed node E.